# Facebook Post Shares Scrapping

Tags: python, web-scraping, facebook-graph-api

I have a script that extract the number of shares of a facebook post.

```
from facebook_scraper import get_posts
 
post_df_full=pd.DataFrame()

posts = get_posts(
    "RealMadrid", extra_info=True, pages=3, 
    options={"comments": True, "shared_username": True}
)
for post in posts:
    post_entry=post
    fb_post_df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(post_entry, orient="index")
    fb_post_df=fb_post_df.transpose()
    post_df_full=pd.concat([post_df_full, fb_post_df], axis=0)
print(post["post_id"]+" get")
```

But, I would like to extract the shares of the post: who shared and where he shared?

Answer (score 0):

As according to a comment on [this issue](https://github.com/kevinzg/facebook-scraper/issues/814), adding `'sharers': True` to the `options` parameter will have the generator include a list of sharers.

However, when I tried it, the list had the names and profile URLs of the people who shared, but not the times at which the post was shared. If you ***really*** want the time, I suppose you could scrape each sharer and see the time for a post with a matching `shared_post_id`...

Another issue I noticed was that the sharers are also not included every time - sometimes some specific sharers are missing even though they were returned in a previous call, and sometimes there is only an empty list; but then, as the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/facebook-scraper/) mentioned:

> There is no guarantee that every field will be extracted

It's still possible that you might get more consistent results, so it's definitely worth a try.

Comment: Yeah that is the problem I faced